# Concat then delete source files in Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

New to Gulp, using v4 (alpha), learning as I go. I'm thinking of an optimized build process and am at a point where I want to concatenate files (`gulp-concat`) and delete (`del`) the source files in 1 step. (my build process copies files from the `source` location to the `build` destination, and then only works on files there, rather than directly on `source` files (as a practice). Once I `concat` the files, I don't want them in the `build`, and want to `del`ete them afterwards. FYI, the `dest` variable just points to the build folder based on flags set when run (`./build/` for development builds and `./dist/` for  deployment builds.)

```
gulp.src(dest + 'assets/scripts/**/*.js')
  .pipe(gulp.concat('combined.js')
  // ??? (stuck here)
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but at this point in the pipe, I've lost reference to my "source" files, and only the `combined.js` file is sitting in the pipe. I could `gulp.dest()` and save it, but as I understand it that creates a `writeStream` which I cannot continue to the next `.pipe()`, right? On top of that, the `del` plugin does not seem to return a stream, so I'm not sure if I could use it in a pipe, but I just want to ensure it only runs after I've done the concatenation.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you copy your scripts to the destination folder before working on them ? Especially if you want to delete them in the end anyway...
One of the reason I like gulp is that you don't have to create temporary files 99% of the time : take your sources, apply some transformations and then write them to their destination.

Comment: I guess as long as I know the scripts that ARE going to be concatenated can be omitted from the copying process, I could keep them in the SRC so they would not have to be deleted afterwards from the build. I would just have to define a glob pattern in my config file which specifies the files, in order, and then see if I can use that same glob, negated, when it comes to copying over styles from src to build.